# How to import Parcel JS generated bundles into "legacy" application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, parceljs

I'm working with an application with a front end built using old school techniques (jQuery and direct DOM manipulation) and I would like to move it over to ES8 and React. Since this is a rather large and complex application, this move will have to be gradual, meaning both the legacy code and React code will have to live side by side for some time.

The legacy code uses a home brew "module loader", which need to keep working. I've been looking at using Webpack and its configuration option `libraryTarget: 'var'`, which basically outputs each entry point into a global variable. This works but the performance (build time) of Webpack isn't good enough so I have been looking at using ParcelJS instead.

Is it possible to achive something similar as Webpack's `libraryTarget: 'var'` with ParcelJS? Basically, in a "legacy HTML file" (which often times is server generated and may contain data I need to pass on to the ES8 modules), I would like to be able to do somethings along lines of

```
<script src="dist/js/ABundle.js"></script> <!-- Bundle created by ParceJS -->
<script>
    var data = {/* JSON generated by server */};
    var ABundle = require('ABundle'); // Export defined in ABundle.js.
    ABundle.render(data); // Function exported in ABundle.
</script>
```

Note that i cannot pass my HTML files as entry points to ParcelJS as they contain references to Javascript files using the homebrew module loader which won't play nice with ParcelJS. I only want to pass the ES8 modules as entry points to ParcelJS and use them side by side with the home brew module loader.

EDIT: Clarified that legacy HTML is in fact server generated.

Comment: This sounds like it will take a lot of effort to get your hybrid app working, and even then I wonder how you will combine React with direct DOM manipulation... In other words, won’t it be more valuable if you just start porting to React directly? Even if it takes more time. Just thinking out loud here.

Comment: I've actually ported a fairly large part of the application using webpack and the `libraryTarget: 'var'` approach. This works fine but the webpack build takes forever (i.e > 30 seconds) which is the reason I would like to switch to Parcel JS (which builds the app in about 1.5 seconds, initial tests show). So the actual code and porting is already a "solved problem", I just need to find a way to use the code when bundled using Parcel JS.

Comment: I once had a webpack project that took 10+ seconds to compile, but the cause was that `caching` was disabled. Once enabled, webpack only took 1 second to compile.

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this? I need to do the same. One option is using SystemJS to import the module. It returns the root module you built with Parcel--I have no idea how it figures it out. I'd prefer not to have that extra library for just one call though. You can also have modules advertise themselves by adding to a global like window.myModules. That's cheap but at little weird.